# style of text selected (highlighted) with a mouse in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying use a [Bootstrap 3 template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/) and change how highlighted text looks.

By Default, when you select a word with a mouse, it is blue with a white background. I wanted to change only the blue color to sort of red, but when I use the following css, it overwrites whole styling:

```css
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
    color: rgba(217,83,79,0.50);
 }

 ::selection {
    color: rgba(217,83,79,0.50);
 }
```

Here's an example:

[image: screenshot]

I've searched CSS files of bootstrap and the template but I can't find any styling. I was searching for `::selection`. How can I find it?

Comment: try using like this `*::-moz-selection {...` , `*::-webkit-selection {..` and `*::selection {...` . you can define both `background` as well as `color` in all of them.

Comment: thanks mate, however `*` doesn't do if for me. it overwrites all the styling, and I want to replace only the blue color and leave the rest as it is.

Answer (score 4):

You should specify both the `color` and the `background` of the selected text.

> **Warning**: Browser implementation of `::selection` is not standardized and the [spec for css 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-selection) is not yet approved.  That said, according to [caniuse ::selection](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection), browser support looks pretty good.

Here's an example of the code below as run in several browsers.  Notice that FF and IE by default will theme selections based on the background color to make them more noticeable, while chrome will not.  Chrome will also prevent any truly white selection background against a dark themed background.

[image: Cross Browser Example]

#### Here's a Demo in Stack Snippets

```css
.dark  { color: #fff; background-color: #333;}
.light { color: #333; background-color: #fff;}

::-moz-selection { color: #D9534F;  background: #fff; }
::selection      { color: #D9534F;  background: #fff; }
```

```html
<div class="dark" >Dark-Themed </div>
<div class="light">Light-Themed</div>
```

#### [Here's a Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/av3hngLy/)

For more info, read up on [MDN on the `::selection` psuedo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aselection) or on [this article on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/)